# How do I loop through my data in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my JSON data structure in Firebase database:

```
familylist
 |- 0
    |--children
    |   |-- 0:"FGH"
    |   |-- 1:"HJU"
    |-- code: "2222"
    |-- family: "SWE"
    |-- fatherName: "ABC"
    |-- motherName: "XYZ"
```

The problem is I have to loop through my entire loop. Hence I can't hard code the database reference value to 0,1,.. etc every time I check a condition whether the user's entered code matched with this `code` field.
For example:

```
 familyListReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("familylist/0/family");
```

I'm able to get a single value from a particular location with this below code. But, How can I change my code so that I can traverse in a loop and can get what ever data that I'd like to pull up.

```
// Read from Database
familyListReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String familyName = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    Log.d(TAG, "Family name is: " + familyName);
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference familyListReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("familylist");
familyListReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = (String) ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference keyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("familylist").child(key);
            keyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String code = dataSnapshot.child("code").getValue(String.class);
                    String family = dataSnapshot.child("family").getValue(String.class);
                    String fatherName = dataSnapshot.child("fatherName").getValue(String.class);
                    String motherName = dataSnapshot.child("motherName").getValue(String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Read failed");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Didn't work. It is reaching till here only!
`Family list Ref: https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist` when I logged the output in LogCat. I have to manually write "`0`" inorder to get the values at that particular `0`th position. Is there any way that I can do that programatically?
It is not entering `for loop` as well. Don't know why!

Comment: Please see my updated code in which i was assuming that the `familylist` node is the first child after your root. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Root --> familylist --> 0 ---> all other fields. This is the flow.

Comment: With the new `DatabaseReference` still not working? What is the error now?

Comment: Yes. Still isn't working! `Family list Ref: https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist` this is the new Reference ( the same ) . It should be `https://bcm.firebaseio.com/familylist/0` right ? How can I do that programatically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144862/discussion-between-pc-and-alex-mamo).